# Visual Studio: Show elapsed time for line of codes

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, performance, visual-studio-2022

In earlier versions of Visual Studio, the elapsed time for every line of code (C#) during a debug run could displayed within the code view near to the line number.

I couldn't find any similar feature in the current 2022 version of Visual Studio.
Is this still a feature and what do I have to do to enable it?

Comment: That doesn't sound right to me. At least, I've never seen that. What I have seen is the time since the last break displayed at the end of a line of code each time you step in the debugger and that still works exactly the same way in VS 2022. Is that what you're talking about? For instance, if you set a breakpoint and, when it's hit, press F10 to step to the next line, the time taken to execute the previous line will be displayed at the end of the current line.

Comment: I also remember a feature I saw about 10 to 15 years ago. It was only available in the most expensive version of Visual Studio. When you enabled it, the duration of each line was shown.

Comment: Putting the execution time of the previous statement after the next, to-be-executed statement is a bug only Microsoft dare to consider as a feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's still available in VS 2022. See screenshot below.

[image]

To enable it, go to `Debug menu`, choose `Options`.

Check `Show elapsed PerfTip while debugging` option